# From where do asteroids get water from?

Tags: water

We all know that the water on Earth came from asteroids that collided on the Earth. But how does water form in the asteroids?

Comment: The sentence "We all know that the water on Earth came from asteroids" seems a bit strong. As far as I know the origin of water on Earth is still being debated:  https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8206/do-did-the-asteroids-contain-enough-water-to-create-earths-oceans. As can be seen in the answer to https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10277/how-did-water-get-on-earth there are still differences in the deuterium content between Earth and the asteroids.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in astronomy.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please do not multi-post, you [already asked this question](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/20389/1462) on astronomy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you already [asked it](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20389/how-was-water-formed) on astronomy SE, a community better suited to answer this question because the answer is essentially *from the stars* (although planetary science is on-topic here).

Comment: While already answered, the answer is also basically explained here:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frost_line_(astrophysics)

Comment: That question was about how water formed on Earth. Here I am asking as to how water was formed in the asteroids at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

hydrogen is the most common element in the universe, Oxygen is the third most common element in the universe, hydrogen + oxygen + heat/energy = water. Water is literally the most common compound in the universe.